# Error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added : Lokio/AsyncTimeout

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, nuget-package

> Dear Developer, We identified one or more issues with a recent
>   delivery for your app, "xyz" 1.0 (1.59). Please correct the following
>   issues, then upload again. ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps
>   that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for
>   improved security and reliability. Learn more
>   (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview). Though
>   you are not required to fix the following issues, we wanted to make
>   you aware of them: ITMS-90683: Missing Purpose String in Info.plist -
>   Your app's code references one or more APIs that access sensitive user
>   data. The app's Info.plist file should contain a
>   NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription key with a user-facing purpose
>   string explaining clearly and completely why your app needs the data.
>   Starting Spring 2019, all apps submitted to the App Store that access
>   user data are required to include a purpose string. If you're using
>   external libraries or SDKs, they may reference APIs that require a
>   purpose string. While your app might not use these APIs, a purpose
>   string is still required. You can contact the developer of the library
>   or SDK and request they release a version of their code that doesn't
>   contain the APIs.

To fix this I have updated my xamarin.forms version to 4.6 and it's working fine in iOS but in Android when I'm trying to run the app I'm getting this java.lang.IllegalArgumentException error. What I'm missing and what I have to follow?

Comment: Did you update XF on the Android side too?

Comment: Yes, I have updated XF in all projects